# HP P410 offline RAID expansion and migration

Tags: raid, ubuntu-16.04, hp-smart-array, raid10

I have a 2 x 146GB SAS in RAID1. I bought 2 more, same specs drive. I am on a production server. I have a P410 with 512MB cache, but no battery. I can afford a downtime.

My questions are:

1. Can I load ACU boot CD and add the new drives, in offline mode?
2. After I added the drives to the array, can I migrate the RAID level from 1, to 10, offline?
3. Is my data gonna be safe?

I still don't get it if P410 without a battery, which is needed for online migration and other operations, will allow me to do this offline, as I have no battery for the cache.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By HP Website : 
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03510253
you  Can extend the Array.
i would recommend a backup any way.
but you do need the cache battery.
unless it won't be successful and you might lose your DATA.